# Data synchronization between two databases

Tags: sql, web-services, windows-services, synchronization

I need to synchronize between two data sources:

I have a web service running on then net. It continuously gathers data from the net and stores it on the database. It also provides the data to the client based on the client's request. I want to keep a repository of data as object for faster service.

On the client side, there is a windows service that calls the web service mentioned previously and synchronize its local database to the server.

Few of my restrictions:

- The web service has very small buffer limit and it can only transfer less then 200 records per call which is not enough for data collected in a day.
- I also can't copy the database files since the database structure is very different (sql and other is access)
- The data is being updated on a hourly basis and there will be large amount of data that will be needed to be transfer.
- Sync by date or other group is not possible with the size limitation. Paging can be done but the remote repository keeps changing (and I don't know how to take chunk of data from the middle of table of SQL database)

*How do I use the repository for recent data update/or full database in sync with this limitation?*

A better approach for the problem or an improvement of the current approach will be taken as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that syncing by date or by group wouldn't work because the number of records would be too big, but what about syncing by date (or group or whatever) and then paging by that? The benefit is that you will have a defined batch of records and you can now page over that because that group won't change.

For example, if you need to pull data off hourly, as each hour elapses (so, when it goes from 8:59am to 9:00 am), you begin pulling down the data that was added between 8am and 9am in chunks of 200 or whatever size the service can handle.